# Minimum string as per String#CompareTo

Tags: java, string, compareto

Ok, I'm sure that this must exist on here somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Is there, and if there is what is, a minimum (non-null) `String` sequence according to `String#CompareTo`?

I'm guessing `""` but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: do u mean string.Empty; ?

Comment: @Mikatsu what is that?

Comment: string.Empty is a string with a length of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the implementation of `String#compareTo` (see [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html)) you can verify that a string of size 0 (thus the empty string) will always be inferior or equal to any other non null string. (equal in case of comparing to the empty string).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Try this,

```
   String s="";
      String s1=new String(new char[-2]);  // Here you will get NagativeArraySize Exception
     System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s));
```

Here compareTo returns nothing in System.out.println(), so the minimum string will be "" or String.Empty

---

AFAIK, There is no minimum lenght and you can not find a string with the length <0, so the minimum length for the string 0 (string.Empty or "").

Check this source code of CompareTo ,

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
        int len1 = count;       // original string count
        int len2 = anotherString.count;  // comparision string count
        int n = Math.min(len1, len2);       
        char v1[] = value;
        char v2[] = anotherString.value;
        int i = offset;
        int j = anotherString.offset;

        if (i == j) {
            int k = i;
            int lim = n + i;
            while (k < lim) {
                char c1 = v1[k];
                char c2 = v2[k];
                if (c1 != c2) {
                    return c1 - c2;
                }
                k++;
            }
        } else {
            while (n-- != 0) {
                char c1 = v1[i++];
                char c2 = v2[j++];
                if (c1 != c2) {
                    return c1 - c2;
                }
            }
        }
        return len1 - len2;
    }
```

Comment: I wasn't asking for the minimum length, but +1 for the code that answers the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no minimum length, since you can validly compare two empty strings with `"".compareTo("")`

Comment: Well, the length can't be less than 0 so "" is effectively the minimum length, no?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that was implicit. I.e. that there is no minimum length sequence for this particular operation other than the minimum length of a String

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I wasn't asking for minimum length, I was asking for the minimum String as per lexicographic ordering.

Comment: I see, I must have misunderstood. Perhaps you could say that in the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a empty String with not values in it.

Take a look at this sample code :

```
String str = "";
str.compareTo("");
```

Comment: While this apparently has the right answer, the example doesn't really prove that...

Answer (score 0):

Yes the minimum length string will be an empty string "" with a length of 0. I don't think there will be such a string with length less than 0.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I wasn't asking for minimum length, I was asking for the minimum String as per lexicographic ordering.